# renaming file with php not working

Tags: php, ajax

by clicking on button I'm making ajax call to rename a file, i get the ajax success respond that I'm echoing from php file, but file isn't renaming.
below is my file structure

admin (root)

-swap.php (inside admin folder)

-edit.php (ajax function is inside this file) (inside admin folder)

upload (root)
- file/s to be renamed in this upload folder

---

edit.php

```
$(".swap").click(function(){
        var originalPic = $("#originalPic").attr("src");
        var newPic = $(this).attr("data-file"); 
        var dataString = 'old='+ originalPic + '&new='+ newPic; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "swap.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

swap.php

```
$originalPic = $_POST['old'];
$newPic = $_POST['new'];

$temp = "/uploads/tempname";

$imgUrl = "/uploads/";

$originalPic = $imgUrl . basename($originalPic).PHP_EOL;
$newPic = $imgUrl . basename($newPic).PHP_EOL;
$temp = $imgUrl . basename($temp).PHP_EOL;

rename($originalPic, $originalPic . 'tmp' . PHP_EOL);

echo "done";
```

main goal is to swap out the file names of two file (originalPic and newPic), but currently I'm just trying to add tmp at the end of name, but thats not working.

Comment: Does the directory where it's supposed to happen have the proper permissions set?

Comment: upload directory contents is there from web form submits, so yes it does have correct write permissions

Comment: Why are you trying to add EOL strings to your filenames?

Comment: because on one of the other page where I'm viewing those pics, it wouldn't show the pics until i added EOL. so i figured may be that was causing it not to rename.

Comment: i have tried without EOL still not renaming

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also, make sure you check the file extension or you may get hacked.

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  rename(/uploads/1442246290
,/uploads/1442246290
.tmp): No such file or directory in <b>/home/mlerma1/public_html/admin/swap.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br /> thats the error, but file is there.